# How to open deeplink of iOS application on real iOS device via Command Line?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ipa, deeplink

As it is possible to open deep-link of .apk app on Android real device via command line with help ABD Shell how can we do the same action for iOS ?

Condition: The iOS device is connected to MAC, the app is installed and I have a list of deeplinks of current app.